# Number of ways to park 9 cars of 2 colours in a row

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Nine cars are parked in a row. Four identical cars are painted red and five identical cars are painted blue. How many ways can the cars be parked in a line so that there are never two red cars next to each other?

I know the answer is $15$.
My question is, if a problem specifies that the objects are identical, does that mean we dont need to count the ways these objects can be rearranged?
For example in this problem we do not need to include the number of ways to arrange the blue cars ($5!$)? I always seem to over-count or undercount.

Comment: It is not necessary to count rearrangements of identical objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a good method. I use the same formula, but I thought about it differently. Line up all 5 reds, and then there is 6 spots to put a blue to appeal to the constraint. i.e '* r * r * r * r * r *' -- See? So to then choose 4 places for blue, it's $C(6,4)$

And actually, I like figuring the whole thing out, incase in the future I have moree challenging problems.

$C(5,5)*C(6,4)$

Answer (score 1):

the number of ways to arrange is $5$ multi choose $2$  which is $5-1 + 2 \choose 2 .$

here is one way to see this: first distribute $4$ reds and separate the reds with $3$  blues like $*r*br*br*br*$ with the $5$ spaces marked by $*.$  the remaining $2$ blue cars can be parked in ones or twos in any of the five places. that is you have $5$ multi choose $2$ ways to put the remaining $2$ blue.